# How can I read Lusztig's papers on Weyl groups and Hecke algebras?

Tags: reference-request

I have to read the following papers and books by Lusztig this semester:

> 1. G. Lusztig, Cells in affine Weyl groups, in book" Algebraic Groups and Related Topics"(R. Hotta, ed.), Advanced Studies in Pure Math., Kinokuniya and North Holland,(1985), 255--287.
> 2. G. Lusztig, Cells in affine Weyl groups, II, J. Algebra, 109(1987), 536--548.
> 3. G. Lusztig, Cells in affine Weyl groups, IV, J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo Sect. IA. Math., 36 (1989),297--328.
> 4. G. Lusztig,  Hecke algebras with unequal parameters (book), CRM Monograph Series, vol. 18, AMS, USA, 2003.
> 5. G. Lusztig,  Hecke algebras and Jantzen's generic decomposition patterns, Adv. in Math., 37(1980),121-164.

I know they are all on MathSciNet, but I don't have access to it.

So would anyone please give me some advice as to getting access to these papers and books?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't get access through your institution's libraries in someform?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Thanks. In fact, yes... I am in a university, but I can't get access in the library. Some friends tried to enter this site through their campus networks, but they also failed...

Comment: You can't get access to the physical library?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: I am very sorry I don't know about the physical library. I searched and found the papers on MathSciNet(www.ams.org/mathscinet/), but I could not read them.

Comment: You can't read the papers on MathSciNet; that site will just give reviews of the papers. Doesn't your university have an actual physical library that you can open a door to and talk inside with a working librarian about your reference requests?

Comment: @KCd: I am sorry. When I saw "physical", I thought of something like gravity... I looked for them in our actual physical library before I searched them on the web. They are so hard to find maybe because they are not published recently...

Comment: Ask a librarian there if the university library can obtain copies of those journal volumes (or at least the articles in the journals) and books by interlibrary loan.

Comment: @KCd: Thank you very much. I will try some other methods.